# Error retrieving data via ARM generated dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I try to deploy a dashboard with a log analytics query-based plot. Deployment is going well, however, the result is error receiving data on the dashboard. Any ideas on how to fix it?

I tried all the ways to generate equals to manually created ones, but it doesn't work in any case. The only difference is in the `PartId` missed section, but I don't have an idea of how to get it or provide some. Hardcoding or omitting doesn't work. Like

```
{
   "name": "PartId",
   "value": "deb07eda-e7e2-4d53-8bb0-9fb5c99306fc" 
},
```

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Url": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "appInsightName":{  
      "type":"string"
   },
   "namePrefix":{
     "type":"string"
   }
  },
  "variables": {
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "lenses": {
          "0": {
            "order": 0,
            "parts": {
              "0": {
                "position": {
                  "x": 9,
                  "y": 0,
                  "colSpan": 6,
                  "rowSpan": 4
                },
                "metadata": {
                  "inputs": [
                    {
                      "name": "ComponentId",
                      "value": {
                        "SubscriptionId": "[subscription().subscriptionId]",
                        "ResourceGroup": "[resourceGroup().Name]",
                        "Name": "Percent Statistics",
                        "ResourceId": "[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup().Name, '/providers/microsoft.insights/components/', parameters('appInsightName'))]"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Query",
                      "value": "..."
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "TimeRange",
                      "value": "P1D"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Dimensions",
                      "value": {
                        "xAxis": {
                          "name": "name",
                          "type": "String"
                        },
                        "yAxis": [
                          {
                            "name": "any_val2",
                            "type": "Int32"
                          }
                        ],
                        "splitBy": [],
                        "aggregation": "Sum"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Version",
                      "value": "1.0"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "PartTitle",
                      "value": "Analytics"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "PartSubTitle",
                      "value": "Percentage"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "resourceTypeMode",
                      "value": "components"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "ControlType",
                      "value": "AnalyticsDonut"
                    }
                  ],
                  "type": "Extension/AppInsightsExtension/PartType/AnalyticsPart",
                  "asset": {
                    "idInputName": "ComponentId",
                    "type": "ApplicationInsights"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "metadata": {
          "model": {
            "timeRange": {
              "value": {
                "relative": {
                  "duration": 24,
                  "timeUnit": 1
                }
              },
              "type": "MsPortalFx.Composition.Configuration.ValueTypes.TimeRange"
            },
            "filterLocale": {
              "value": "en-us"
            },
            "filters": {
              "value": {
                "MsPortalFx_TimeRange": {
                  "model": {
                    "format": "utc",
                    "granularity": "auto",
                    "relative": "24h"
                  },
                  "displayCache": {
                    "name": "UTC Time",
                    "value": "Past 24 hours"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "name": "[concat('db-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Portal/dashboards",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "tags": {
        "hidden-title": ""
      },
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01-preview"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/madiasOnGit/Azure.ARM.Dashboards/blob/master/KustoDashboardExample/azuredeploy.json) helps you.

Comment: No way, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding the `PartId` you can generate it like this:

```
"parameters": { 
      "dashboardName": {
          "type": "string",
          "defaultValue":  "My Custom dashboard"
      }
},

"variables": {
    "dashboardID": "[concat(uniquestring(resourceGroup().id), uniquestring(parameters('dashboardName')))]"
},
```

```
{
   "name": "PartId",
   "value": "[concat(uniquestring(variables('dashboardID')), 'Part1')]"
},
```

Comment: Hi. I've already tried to use this approach form [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/madias/2017/09/11/azure-resource-manager-template-for-an-azure-dashboard-with-log-analytics-tiles/) blog post. however, it doesn't work. @Microsoft confirmed me this article is out of date